# Python - How to fill out a web form then download the file that is generated

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to use use python to go to this page, https://comtrade.un.org/data/, fill in the form, and "click" the download button. Then get the csv file that is generated.

Anyone have some sample code for automating the download in python?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you are accessing has an exposed API and you can use that form to generate the API URL and simply call that to return a JSON or CSV response. To get this with Python you can use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and the core `JSON` module to parse the data if you want to use the data inside Python:

---

### CSV File

```
import requests

api_url = 'https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?max=500&type=C&freq=A&px=HS&ps=2017&r=all&p=0&rg=all&cc=TOTAL&fmt=csv'
response = requests.get(api_url)
data = response.content

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(data)
```

Note the `fmt=csv` property in the URL.

---

### Python Dictionary

```
import requests, json

api_url = 'https://comtrade.un.org/api/get?max=500&type=C&freq=A&px=HS&ps=2017&r=all&p=0&rg=all&cc=TOTAL'
response = requests.get(api_url)
data = json.loads(response.content)

print(data)
```

Note that the API URL in the example came from submitting the default form and clicking 'View API Call'. Under the generated table.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks, @inkychris.

Comment: If this answered your question, could you please mark it as the answer to close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in trying out [pywinauto.](https://pywinauto.github.io/) I have not had too much experience, but I do believe it could do the job.
Good luck!